# An automatic way to crop images of different sizes

Tags: php, images, media

- I have an Affiliate Store with 8000+ Products from over 20 Partnershops.
- I refresh the Products via CSV ( WPALLIMPORT )
- I use Woocommerce
- Each Shop has a different Image-size.
- Some of them have too much with space around the Product so I have to crop center-center
- I'm doing this sequence: go to Media/settings, then add the Image size, then go to Media and search by Shopname (it's in the Front for Example: Zalando21317), then regenerate only these Thumbnails / images from the Shop Zalando, then go to Media/settings change the image size / crop setting, then go to Media and repeat that all with a different shop.

I wonder is there an automatic way of doing this? I searched for hours and didn't find any plugin to fix this.

Comment: i tried any type of crop plugin. But i dont have expierence in programming. so its very difficult for me

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just hardcode the keys for the different crops and then use [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) ?

Comment: sorry i have no clue how :O